# User/administrator updates are out-of-sync. Updated for both user and admin but nothing happened

Tags: miktex, texstudio

So every time I run code on TeXStudio, I would get

`User/administrator updates are out-of-sync.`

I have updated MikTeX as both admin and user on my machine, but I still get this message. How to fix this?

Note: I also realized that on TeXStudio, whenever I would run the file, I would get:

```
Process started: lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "ThisFile".tex

lualatex: major issue: User/administrator updates are out-of-sync.

Process exited normally
```

Supposedly, the pdf file appears after this, but the first two lines appear again and I have to wait for the same amount of run time again before `Process exited normally` appears. I wonder if it's due to out-of-sync warning?

Comment: How did you update as user and as admin? Did you switch the modes in the MiKTeX console?

Comment: Yes I did. I updated from both modes but it didn’t work.

Comment: Please keep in mind that out-of-sync can mean: 1) user updates are _behind_ admin updates 2) user updates are _ahead_ admin updates. If 1), you have to update in user mode first. If 2), you have to update in admin mode first.

Comment: How would one know which one is which?

Comment: MiKTeX Console shows either "Stay in MiKTeX user mode and check for updates." or "Switch to MiKTeX administrator mode and check for updates.". This update hell scenario is the reason why it is better to install MiKTeX for the current user only.

Comment: So if that’s the case, if I want to fix the problem, should I update the user first, then the admin?

Comment: @ChristianSchenk 's comment did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. The solution to this issue is in the [reply by Christian Schenk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546994/user-administrator-updates-are-out-of-sync-updated-for-both-user-and-admin-but#comment1382054_546994):

> Please keep in mind that out-of-sync can mean: 1) user updates are behind admin updates 2) user updates are ahead admin updates. If 1), you have to update in user mode first. If 2), you have to update in admin mode first.

Hence, if you don't not know which case applies to you, i.e., either 1) or 2), start by assuming that it is case 1) i.e., update in admin mode first and only afterwards in user mode. If the message "User/administrator updates are out-of-sync." stops appearing, it means that in fact case 1) applies to you. If it keeps on appearing, it means that case 2) applies to you and, since you have already updated in user mode, update once more in  admin mode.

This worked for me.